# Can I specify a payment ID when using the sweep_all command?

Tags: payment-id, sweep-transaction

Is it possible to use a payment id with the sweep_all command, and if so, is the syntax simply:

sweep_all address payment_id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it's undocumented, but I just tested with version 0.10 and it behaves as expected with your syntax.
`sweep_all <address> <payment_id>`

Comment: This is correct. You can use mixins as well. Sweep_all has the same options as a transfer command, far as I know.